# how to "look in" on a multiprocessing pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a bit of multi-processing code that looks like below.  When I kick off this job, everything is great, and I see my queue size decreasing rapidly.  Then a little more slowly.  Then it is not making any progress at all.  But I can still see 12 python processes running.

I suspect that there is some error that big_hairy_routine is hitting, and the processes are slowly dying off.  But how can I peek into the async_result structure to see the state of the underlying pool processes?

(It's also possible that I'm using the wrong idiom here.)

```
import traceback
import multiprocessing
from Queue import Empty

def do_something(q):
    item = q.get_nowait()
    while item:
        try:
           big_hairy_routine(item)
        except Exception, e:
            traceback.print_exc()
            sys.exit(1)

        try:
            item = q.get_nowait()
        except Empty:
            item = None

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
q = manager.Queue()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10)


for item in (1,2,3,4,5):
    q.put(item)

async_result = pool.apply_asnc(do_something, (q,))

while q.qsize > 0:
    print "there are %s items in queue" % q.qsize()
    if async_result.ready():
        print "we're done!"
        break
    time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: I had a similar issue with the threading module. There, you have to specify `q.task_done()` when a process is finished. Are you missing something like that here? (Sorry if this is off-topic.)

Comment: why are you calling sys.exit(1) in the except: clause? shouldn't that raise an exception and render the thread useless? maybe a better approach would be to log the error then pass so the thing can keep working...

Comment: sys.exit(1) will cause the process to terminate, thus killing all currently running threads in the process (unless your threads spawn separate processes).  There are various reasons why you might want to do this -- it depends on what the threads do, but if the threads depend on each other in some way this behavior makes perfect sense.

Comment: You should determine if the threads are alive but have become zombies.

Comment: They're not threads. They're processes.  I'm desperately trying to figure out why they're getting stuck -- or how to see what is stuck or dead.  (From the OS, I can see that the processes are still alive, but they don't seem to be doing anything.)  In my real code, I'm trying log an error before exiting...but nothing ever shows up.